# Reat can't send POST request to Spring Boot app

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, api, http-post

I have following problem: I created Spring Boot API, which shares some endpoints. I also have filter, which determine which endpoints can be reached with/without JSON Web Token. It all works fine, Postman returns correct objects, but React can't handle with it. I don't know what may cause problems.

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Login API:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowedHeaders = "*")
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
            userDetails.getId(),
            userDetails.getUsername(),
            roles));
}
```

Fragment of React code:

```
const authenticate = async () => {
let usr = {
  username: userName,
  password: password
};
await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/auth/login`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(usr)
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

}

Request comes to server, because during debugging I can read all data on server side. Also i figured out that until whole request is processed, React cancels the request. I tried with different API (e.g. https://www.balldontlie.io/#get-all-games) and fetch returns code 200.

[Cancelled request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pP69.png)

**EDIT**

I can get data from another API endpoint, but I have to add JWToken by myself in fetch/axios request:

```
const getInitBooks = async () => {
await axios("http://localhost:8080/api/books/all", {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTU5MTE4MDkwMiwiZXhwIjoxNTkxMTgxODAyfQ.aN8mch_CCgeByLGDUkstiNLxV7x3364OEUeDgqyfWVQ"
  },
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  setBooks(response.data)
  setInitBooks(response.data)
});
```

So error is only with POST requests. I don't know what can be wrong now.

**SOLUTION**

I figured it out, it wasn't Spring problem, but adding `e.preventDefault()` in React function worked.

Code snippet:

```
const authenticate = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
await axios({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/authentication/login/",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    username: userName,
    password: password
  },
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  setLoggedIn(true);
})
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When I add my request path
(`localhost:8686/app/addStudent`) of POST method in antMatchers method, it works successfully:

```
http
     .csrf().disable()
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/","/app/**").permitAll()
     .anyRequest()
     .authenticated()
     .and()
     .httpBasic();
```